# update query dosen't work

Tags: php, mysql, join, rank

```
SELECT codefard,ave,class,
      IF(ave=@_last_ave,@curRank:=@curRank,@curRank:=@_sequence) AS rank,
       @_sequence:=@_sequence+1,@_last_ave:=ave
    FROM grade, (SELECT @curRank := 1, @_sequence:=1, @_last_ave:=0) r
    ORDER BY  ave DESC
```

this query works correctly but when i update this answer into table doesn't work.

```
UPDATE grade JOIN (SELECT codefard,ave,class,
   IF(ave=@_last_ave,@curRank:=@curRank,@curRank:=@_sequence) AS rank,
              @_sequence:=@_sequence+1,@_last_ave:=ave
    FROM grade, (SELECT @curRank := 1, @_sequence:=1, @_last_ave:=0) r
    ORDER BY  ave DESC)as d ON grade.codefard = d.codefard SET grade.allrank=d.rank
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is so nebulous as to be practically useless in attempting to discern what *behavior* is being observed, what outcome we are expecting, and how it is we are determining that the outcome is differs from what we expect. (is the query execution throwing an error? returning "0 row(s) affected"? updating rows but the table contents after the update are not what we expected? is codefard the primary key or unique key in `grade`? why is that column used in the join predicate?)

Comment: personally, i'd write the rank expression as `@curRank := IF(ave=@last_ave,@curRank,@_sequence) AS rank`. Note that MySQL Reference Manual cautions about behavior of user-defined variables that are set and read in the same statement. The order of operations that we expect may not be the order of operations that MySQL performs.

Comment: The MySQL manual does not specify any behaviour if you update & read a variable in the same select statement. Percona employees have shown that *in the current implementation* you can do it with a defined result using case expressions in a certain way. But it's still not guaranteed to work next release. PS Please read & act on [ask] & [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for sharing a status report... "here's some SQL that doesn't work". Cool story bro. I'm just wondering, was there a *question*?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing

```
UPDATE tablename SET username = 'newname';
```

it should work
Thank's

Comment: thanks for your help .this syntax is correct  .for example:          UPDATE grade ,(SELECT codefard, ave, FIND_IN_SET( ave, (
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( ave
   ORDER BY ave DESC ) 
   FROM grade )
   ) AS rank
   FROM grade)as r SET grade.allrank=r.rank WHERE grade.codefard = r.codefard

Comment: This was your love to share us. I'm also apprentice

Answer (score 0):

why dosen't work this query properly

```
UPDATE player  
    JOIN (SELECT p.playerID,  
                 IF(@lastPoint <> p.points,  
                    @curRank := @curRank + @nextrank,  
                    @curRank)  AS rank,  
                 IF(@lastPoint = p.points,  
                    @nextrank := @nextrank + 1,  
                    @nextrank := 1),  
                 @lastPoint := p.points  
            FROM player p  
            JOIN (SELECT @curRank := 0, @lastPoint := 0, @nextrank := 1) r  
           ORDER BY  p.points DESC  
          ) ranks ON (ranks.playerID = player.playerID)  
SET player.rank = ranks.rank;
```